# multi-developer development setting with Git

Tags: git

First of all, I'm a fresher in Git. I come from SVN background, where developers work through checking in/out code against a shared repository.

What do I do with Git to enable multi-developer development?

From my understanding, is it correct if each developer will have his/her own individual local repository for each, but share one remote repository that would sit somewhere on the server.

Is my understanding correct? Where do I find a good reading on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your understanding is correct. You don't have to do anything to "enable" a multi-developer scenario.

You just need a repo where everyone can push changes to (and pull changes from).

[This](http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766290565/how-set-up-your-own-private-git-server-linux) might help you.

**Edit**

Let me add a few more words. Even if git is a *distributed* source code management system, most of the times you will still have a "blessed" central repository, one you will consider to be your "official" one.

The difference is that, git being distributed, every developer will have a clone of that official repo, containing all the entire history.

The many reasons why this is such a **Good Idea®**, well, you'll figure them out on your own, trust me.

Answer (score 1):

There are

1. **Local Version Control Systems** (locally on your dev machine, e.g. when you check out code)
2. **Centralized Version Control Systems** (like svn, cvs)
3. **Distributed Version Control Systems** (like git, bazaar, mercurial)

The workflow of **Distributed Version Control Systems** like git in combination with github is the following:

- repository (3) owner

  - grants access to project contributors
  - approves pull request (explained later)
- contributor

  - forks the remote project and has it available in his repository account (3)
  - clones the project and has it available locally (1)
  - commits locally and pushes changes to his project repository as necessary (so changes are not lost when his local machine crashes...)
  - during development he fetches and merges commits from the remote (main) repository regularly so he stays close to ongoing development trunk
  - if he has a working solution he sends a pull request to the repository owner
- repository owner

  - accepts or denies the pull request
  - if accepted, the changes are merged to the main repository

**Important:** This repository "hierarchy" can be extended to other contributors which are contributors of your repository.

Good resources are the following:

- [Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/)
- [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/)
- [git Reference](http://gitref.org/)
- [github Help](http://help.github.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about Git is that it is extremely flexible. The best workflow for your situation is completely dependent on how you and your co-developers like to interact.

To get up and running in a multi-developer environment all you need to do is have some way to fetch / push between your repositories. This can either be directly between each other or via a central authority, or 'blessed' repository and can be done via ssh, a file share, https or even just duct-taping a thumb drive containing the 'blessed' repository to a carrier pigeon.

An excellent free resource when it comes to helping you get started is [Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/), which includes a good chapter on [Distributed Workflows](http://progit.org/book/ch5-1.html). Also, have a look at ["A successful branching model"](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for a well designed way to keep everything organised.